# Analytics for Google Calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-analytics

I need to find out how many people use my public Google Calendar and I am unable to find any way of integrating analytics. Is this possible?

Comment: Voting to close because Stack Overflow is not the Google Customer Support. This is not a coding problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a website there is a way to do this, but it takes a little coding.

Go to calendar settings and find "Embed This Calendar", then embed it in your website by copy/pasting the embed code. Install Google Analytics on the website and track views to the page with your calendar.

This may not work, depending on how you share your public calendar...